# Magento 2: How to increase the column max length?

Tags: magento2, database, column, db-schema

I want to increase the customer firstname max length so I have updated the length of that column using my custom module `dbschema.xml`.

After updating the length, I can see the updated length in PHPMyAdmin but when I check the column length using the below query, it's showing the older length

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'customer_entity';
```

Can anyone please confirm whether this is the right way to increase the field length?

Comment: I think you have to convert firstname into text type and so length column would be empty

Answer (score 0):

This is the way according to Magento 2 doc

```
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Title"/>
```